# Upload Image using android and PHP error

Tags: php, android, file-upload, image-uploading

I have been trying to do uploading image from android through php server watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tEiiUOLemA).

I have done all the same coding shown in this tutorial but my code is not properly working.
Please can you guys check out where I have been doing wrong ?

**my php code**

[image]

Comment: Share your logcat output.

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: @Exception: sorry, but yet i have not been reached to android coding. Its just Php coding which accepts a base64 image and its name. As per code, when i put base 64 image code and name. It doesnot show success as shown in  the video

Comment: What I expect -- http://prntscr.com/b69nr2

what I get  is blank output